# How to draw 2 labels on edge in a .dot file?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have for now a dot file generating the following graph

```
   label
```

[A] ----------->  [b]

and I want to change it to something like:

[A] label 1 ------> label 2 [b]

Is there any way to express that in my .dot file ?  I am not sure this is possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An edge can have a [`taillabel`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dtaillabel) and a [`headlabel`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dheadlabel) attribute:

```
a -> b[headlabel="head", taillabel="tail"];
```

Those labels are displayed near the tail and the head of the edge.

Comment: Just what I was looking for !! I was not able to find that with Google :-(